# Removing portlets on Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I would like to deactivate or, rather, just undeploy most of Liferay's default portlets. I know I can deactivate the portlets through the Liferay control panel one by one or adding a false for each portlet, but I was just wondering if there is a better way (maybe a way of disabling all the portlets and enabling the ones I need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you can disable the portlets loaded by the portal server if you remove their entries from webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\liferay-portlet.xml

Comment: Thanks, I found another way of doing so by modifying the liferay-portlet-ext.xml file. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't hurt anyone if you share the solution @DavidJeong